# 範囲の中にあるかどうかの比較の仕方

Tags: scala

pythonは以下のように簡潔に範囲の中にいる事が比較できますが、

```
3 < x < 7
```

scalaではどうやったら綺麗にかけますか？

Comment: `3 < x && x < 7`以上(?)を求めているのでしょうか？ どちらかといえば`3 < x < 7`と書けるPythonが変わっていますね。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

綺麗かどうかはわからないけど
`(4 until 7).contains(x)`
とは書けます。

Answer (score 3):

`(4 until 7).contains(x)`
や
`(4 to 6).contains(x)`
と書けます。
この様に書いた場合、内部的には`scala.collection.immutable.Range`の[`contains`メソッド](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.7/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/Range.scala#L333)が呼ばれるので、単に`4 <= x && x < 7`を実行するのと同じく定数時間で動作します。